# css or js resize images to fit container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using react + tailwind css

My scenario is : I'll have at most 300 pictures, I shall show these pictures in one screen occupying the most possible space so the images are as big as possible, but all shown in the screen (no overflow).

(Images are at most 300 it could be 10, or 1, for example if it is one it is supposed to fit the screen and occupy the whole space.

For the sake of simplicity the images all have aspect ratio of 1:1

Here's some code I removed the tailwind classes and manually used style because it's easier to understand for the people who haven't worked with tailwind yet.

```
          <div style={{
                display : 'flex',
                alignItems : 'center',
                justifyContent : "center",
                width : 500,
                height : 500,
                backgroundColor : 'red'
            }}>
                <img key={value} src={`/avatars/1.png`} style={{
                    maxWidth : '100%',maxHeight : '100%'
                }}/>
                <img key={value} src={`/avatars/2.png`} style={{
                    maxWidth : '100%',maxHeight : '100%'
                }}/>
                <img key={value} src={`/avatars/3.png`} style={{
                    maxWidth : '100%',maxHeight : '100%'
                }}/>
                <img key={value} src={`/avatars/4.png`} style={{
                    maxWidth : '100%',maxHeight : '100%'
                }}/>
                <img key={value} src={`/avatars/5.png`} style={{
                    maxWidth : '100%',maxHeight : '100%'
                }}/>
            </div>
```

In this example I took it only to 5 but it can be changed, thought using maxWidth and maxHeight of 100% would make it magically work, guess I was wrong.

Comment: How are you adding these photos? I don't think you can do this with CSS alone, since it is content unaware.

Comment: @disinfor hi thank you for the response, I'm using react, so I'm pretty flexible for handling it all through style changes through Javascript if needed

Comment: So you're looking to fill the space with rows and columns of photos if it is more than one where the rows are dynamically created?

Comment: I know you said your own attempts did not work, however, I recommend you add the attempted code to your question. Questions without code and not showing an attempt to solve their issues will undoubtedly be closed and likely down voted.

Comment: @dalelandry Hi thank you for the reply, what do you mean by where they are created?

Seems right I'll add my code right away.

Answer (score 1):

```
.img{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover; // or contain, I never remember these two
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this more of a proof of concept than a full good solution. My knowledge of React is limited so I will present a regular javascript solution. The code should be self-explanatory, but I will give some pointers in how I tackled this problem.

I assume that the square root is the optimal number of images that can fit in a square, so the bottom row wont be filled most of the times.

I control the size of the images by using flex-basis, adding an `aspect-ratio` on them, and then scale the image by setting it as a background with `background-size: cover`.

`generateImageArray(amount)` should be replaced with an array, either hard-coded or something that you get from the server.

```js
const amountOfImagesRange = document.getElementById('amountOfImages');
const imageContainerDiv = document.getElementById('imageContainer');

amountOfImagesRange.addEventListener('change', () => {
  generateImages(amountOfImagesRange.value);
});

function generateImages(amount) {
  let imageArray = generateImageArray(amount);
  let maxPerRow = getMaxPerRow(amount);
    
  clearContainerDiv();
  
  setNumberOfItemsPerRow(maxPerRow);
  
  fillContainerDiv(imageArray);
}

function randomize(max, min) {
  return Math.floor( max * Math.random() + min );
}

function generateImageArray(amount) {
  const MIN_SIZE = 10;
  const MAX_SIZE = 200;
  let imageArr = [], width = 0, height = 0;
  
  while (amount > 0) {
    amount--;
    width  = randomize(MAX_SIZE, MIN_SIZE);
    height = randomize(MAX_SIZE, MIN_SIZE);
    
    imageArr[amount] = `https://picsum.photos/${width}/${height}`;
    ;
  }

  return imageArr;
}

function getMaxPerRow(num) {
  return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(num));
}

function clearContainerDiv() {
  imageContainer.innerHTML = '';
}

function setNumberOfItemsPerRow(maxPerRow) {
  imageContainer.style.setProperty('--images-per-row', maxPerRow);
}

function fillContainerDiv(imageArray) {
  for (let imageSrc of imageArray) {    
    const imgEl = document.createElement("div");

    imgEl.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageSrc})`;
    imageContainer.appendChild(imgEl);
  }
}

generateImages(amountOfImagesRange.value);
```

```css
:root {
  --image-container-size: 500px;
}

#amountOfImages {
  width: 100%;
}

#imageContainer {
  --images-per-row: 5;
  --flex-basis: calc(100% / var(--images-per-row));

  width: var(--image-container-size);
  height: var(--image-container-size);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  flex-basis: var(--flex-basis);

  outline: 1px solid; 
}

#imageContainer > div {
  width: 100%;
  flex-basis: var(--flex-basis);
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="amountOfImages" value="25" min="10" max="300">

<div id="imageContainer"></div>
```